# to be 99% certain of making a profit? central limit theorem?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

[image]

Let $X_i$ be the profit card $i$ makes when its sold. I let $S_n = X_1 + ... + X_n$ so total profit.

I found the mean of $X$ to be $0.1$.

and $E[X^2] = 25$ so variance $= 24.99$ Are these correct?

And then I tried to use the central limit theorem.

$P( \frac{S_n -n \mu}{\sigma / \sqrt n} < 2.3263) = 0.99$

But I am trying to find $P(S_n>0)$ right? how would i do this?

Thanks.

Comment: What you've done is right, you've got the good mean and variance! The Central Limit Theorem also does say that! But you're saying you are stuck, how could you get something like $P(S_n > ...)=0.99$?

Comment: what do you mean by overall profit?

Comment: thank you both of you for replies. By ovverall profit, I mean what the money at the end would be $= S_n$

Comment: $P( \frac{S_n -n \mu}{\sigma / \sqrt n} < x) = 1 - P( \frac{S_n -n \mu}{\sigma / \sqrt n} \geq x)$ right? But then I am still stuck.

Comment: Am I trying to find n such that $P(S_n > 0) = 0.99$ right?

Comment: I've tried to solve this but I end up with n=0, so my reasoning must be wrong! Sorry I can't help...

Comment: I have got confused. Suppose the company has sold $N$ cards. Then totally it will give $(\frac{N}{100}\times 50)+(\frac{N}{5}\times 2)\frac{9N}{10}$. So the total profit of the company will be $N-\frac{9N}{10}=\frac{N}{10}$. So what do you mean by being $99\%$ sure of making an overall profit?

Comment: That's what I thought too at first, but you have to understand that someone who buys a ticket wins 50 with probability 1%, etc. indeed 1% n cannot always be a natural number, so the data cannot be exact!

Comment: I think you cannot use central limit theorem since the random variables $X_i$, are not independent. Suppose I know the value of $X_1$, so I cannot say that the probability of $P(X_2=-49|X_1=-49)=P(X_2=-49)$. Since totally 1 percent of the cards will win 50 dollars and hence if we know that the first person has won one of the 50 dollars then we can not say the probability that the second person will win the 50 dollars prize is $1\%$. Central limit theorem is used when the random variables are i.i.d.

Comment: I think that you're right as the question was posed, I don't believe it was very well written... @user120227 Try, in the Central Limit Theorem, to consider the sum of $-X_1$, $-X_2$,... then you get $-S_n < ...$ which will give you the required way in the inequality! Watch out for the mean and variance, what are they?

Answer (score 1):

Your $\sigma / \sqrt n$ should be $\sigma \sqrt n$ for the standard deviation of the sum $S_n$ (not the standard deviation of the mean)

If you want the probability that $S_n$ is positive to exceed $0.99$ then you need the probability it is non-positive to be less than $0.01$

so using the Central Limit Theorem to give an approximation, you want to translate $$P\left( \frac{S_n -n \mu}{\sigma \sqrt n} \lt  - 2.3263 \right) \lt 0.01$$ into a requirement that $$n\mu - 2.3263 \sigma  \sqrt n \gt 0$$ i.e. $$ n \gt \dfrac{2.3263^2 \sigma^2}{\mu^2}$$ which with your calculations of the mean seems to suggest $n \gt 13523.77$, giving an answer of $13524$ if I have not made any slips (though this seems rather large)